# The loop and if in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table there are several columns, one is a varchar column called "Country", and another is a boolean column called "SomeFlag", I want to filter all the countries those have "SomeFlag" both 0 and 1 from records.
For example,

```
Record1: country is US, SomeFlag is 0 and some other values.  
Record2: country is US, SomeFlag is 1 and some other values.  
Record3: country is CA, SomeFlag is 1 and some other values.
```

So US is what I want to filter out, how should I construct this SQL query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're saying to eliminate countries which have both row(s) with SomeFlag equal to 0 and other(s) with SomeFlag = 1. Right?

Comment: Yes buddy, that's it. I guess something went wrong with the expression, making it unclear to understand.

Comment: Well you didn't say the name of the table. Substitute that for T in any of my queries and I'll think you'll have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Country from T
group by Country
having min(cast(SomeFlag as int)) = max(cast(SomeFlag as int))
```

or

```
select Country from T
group by Country
having count(distinct SomeFlag) = 1
```

or

```
select Country from T
where not exists (
    select 1 from T
    where SomeFlag = 0
) or not exists (
    select 1 from T
    where SomeFlag = 1
)
```

or

```
select Country from T
where Country not in (
    select Country from T
    group by Country
    having
            min(cast(SomeFlag as int)) = 0
        and max(cast(SomeFlag as int)) = 1
)
```

Do nulls in SomeFlag come into play?

Answer (score 0):

```
"select * from table where (some_flag == '1' or some_flag == '0') and (country == 'US');"
```

Comment: I think it should be a loop to get all the countries.

Answer (score 0):

It will be look like:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE (Table.SomeFlag == 0 OR Table.SomeFlag == 1) AND Table.Country == "US";
```

But if you don't want all information from the table use tags you want, except *.